# Using Arc.Centroid to position a shape, but for some reason X & Y doesnt affect it

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have used Arc.Centroid successfully already on a svg:image. However, when I attempt to use the centroid with a svg.symbol the attr X & Y doesn't affect it -

```
var q = svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", function(d,i) {return "translate ("+ arc[i].centroid() +")";})
 .attr("x",100)
 .attr("y",-40)
  ; 

    q.append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("circle").size(50))
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10, -5)")
    .style("fill", "black");

    q.append("text")
    .text("Hello");
```

From what I can tell this should work. I have also applied another transform attr e.g.

```
var q = svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", function(d,i) {return "translate ("+ arc[i].centroid() +")";})
 .attr("transform", "translate(-150,-150)")
```

But I believe it doesn't translate the shape from the centre of the Arc.. Here's my fiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/29/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `g` element doesn't have `x` and `y` attributes. You can find this kind of information in the SVG spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#GElement

You can move `g` elements around using the `translate` `transform`: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute

For example, the `text` element does have `x` and `y` attributes: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextElement

In your last code snippet you write two different values to the transform attribute. The latter value, `"translate(-150,-150)"`, will overwrite the former one.

```
var q = svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", function(d,i) {return "translate ("+ arc[i].centroid() +")";})
 .attr("transform", "translate(-150,-150)")
```

The SVG transform attribute accepts a list of transform definitions: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute

So the last piece of code should have been written as:

```
 var q = svg.append("g")
     .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
         return "translate ("+ arc[i].centroid() +")" + "translate(100,-40)";
     });
```

If you inspect the `g` element in your browser's Developer Tools (in Chrome right-click, select `inspect element`) you will see:

```
<g transform="translate (-124.42599471897063,11.965443501796923)translate(100,-40)">
  <path d="M0,3.989422804014327A3.989422804014327,3.989422804014327 0 1,1 0,-3.989422804014327A3.989422804014327,3.989422804014327 0 1,1 0,3.989422804014327Z" transform="translate(-10, -5)" style="fill: #000000; "></path>
  <text>Hello</text>
</g>
```

You see two translate operations on the container. http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/30/

Another option would be to group the path and text in another g container. Something like this:

```
<g transform="translate (-124.42599471897063,11.965443501796923)">
  <g transform="translate(100,-40)">
    <path d="M0,3.989422804014327A3.989422804014327,3.989422804014327 0 1,1 0,-3.989422804014327A3.989422804014327,3.989422804014327 0 1,1 0,3.989422804014327Z" transform="translate(-10, -5)" style="fill: #000000; "></path>
    <text>Hello</text>
  </g>
</g>
```

Comment: I just wanted to use the centroid as a way to position the shape. So for example if I move the whole arc, the position of the shape would stay the same - just like the svg:image